# Model is updated even if is invalid

Tags: hibernate, validation, gwt, requestfactory

I'm using GWT RequestFactory to communicate with server. In the server i using hibernate and implement one-session-per-request pattern to control sessions.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

In the model, i put some validations with annotations. The problem is when i try to persist this entity with invalid informations, the validation occur normally returning to view the messages through onViolation method, but that information is saved in the database anyway.

What i discovery is that hibernate always save the model, even if a don't call **save** method.

From the request factory it don't even touch in **persist** method. It stops in the **findXxxx** method.

Any hint of what can i do to solve this? My object is not allow that a entity been persisted with invalid information.

I don't know if this is important for the case, but i using MultiTenancy of hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

RequestFactory mandates one-session-per-request, but that doesn't mean one-transaction-per-request! You should open/close transactions in each and every service method (e.g. your `persist()` method).

Comment: If i don't have a transaction started this way the linked objects are not retrieved. I think the main problem here is not the RquestFatory, but this behavior of hibernate, persisting objects without calling the save method.

Comment: Are you sure you need a **transaction** ? When removing the transaction, did you make sure you kept a one-session-per-request?

Comment: Yes. Without the follow error is thrown: get is not valid without active transaction.

Comment: Then maybe create a transaction in your `findXxx` methods? (and/or `Locator`s)

Comment: Another question. If i use the current session of hibernate set as thread, i think don't need this filter. Is correct?

Comment: Don't you need to close the session at the end of the request? (sorry, I don't use Hibernate)